# The content of some rows is moving when I add content in another row

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `TableLayout` inside a `RelativeLayout`, and I want to dynamically add content to the third row while the first two rows stay the same, but every digit I enter to the `TextView` of the third row makes the `TextView` in the first two rows to move left.
The values of the first two rows are being set in the `onCreate()`, while the third one is set when the user clicks some `Button`.

Is there anything I'm missing?

This is how I set the row3 content dinammically, where the txt object is the `TextView` clicked by the user:

```
TextView form = findViewById(R.id.formula);
form.setText(String.format("%s %s", form.getText(), txt.getText()));
```

Here I post part of the `XML` file (I'm not posting row2 as it's almost the same as row1):

```
    <TableLayout
            <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/Row1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/num1"
                    android:textSize="40sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/num2"
                    android:textSize="40sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/Row3"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/formula"
                    android:textSize="40sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Formula"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnBack"
                    android:text="C"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Comment: do not use fill_parent.. use Match_parant instead of this.. post your code from which you add raw dynamically

Comment: @JJG
I added the lines where I set the value of the TextView.
I also tried using match_parent instead of fill_parent, but I'm still having this problem.